# Java Map data structure that recognizes order of Integers stored as Strings

Tags: java, dictionary

I have the following data:

```
"1" --> "Label 1"
"2" --> "Label 2"
"11" --> "Label 11"
"22" --> "Label 22"
```

which I would like to store in a map that would enforce order of integers, instead of lexicographic order. Is there any *Map that Java already has for this purpose?

Comment: Use a `TreeMap` and provide your own `Comparator` that orders by integer value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TreeMap with custom `Comparator`.

Like:

```
    TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o1), Integer.parseInt(o2));
        }
    });
```

The keys will be ordered according to passed `Comparator`.

Above is just example, but based on your usecase you may change implementation of `compare()` to reflect your business need.

Comment: This doesn't work if the values get really big and can be negative, because the difference can overflow.

Comment: @chiastic-security if values too big, then it will not overflow, but will throw Exception. As OP has only informed about Integer type, and it is solution of that.

Comment: No, I don't mean too big to be parsed. I mean that each one is a valid Integer, but the difference is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. That won't throw an exception, it'll just give wrong answers (which is worse).

Comment: @chiastic-security I updated my answer. And thanks for suggesting integer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a `TreeMap` or a `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, each of which implements `SortedMap`, and allows you to provide a `Comparator` at map creation time.

Either implement it as going from `Integer` as the key, or leave it as a `String` but supply a comparator that works by converting to `Integer` and using that for comparison.

I'd have thought it would be cleaner to use `Integer` as the key, but it won't make much difference.

If you go down the `String` route, do it like this. It's the same as Huko's code, but doesn't go wrong with large negative values where the difference might cause an overflow.

```
TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return Integer.parseInt(o1).compareTo(Integer.parseInt(o2));
    }
});
```

EDIT: Huko's code now takes this into account too.